# Xcode 8.3.2 Crashes when switching devices

Tags: xcode, ios10.3, xcode8

When I switch from generic device to my iphone, xcode unexpectedly quits. I've tried opening other projects (older and newer) and I get the same error. I did not have this error at all before updating to 8.3.2

Stack Trace:

```
Application Specific Information:
MainQueue: -[IDEProvisioningManager _performStateUpdateOnMainThreadForRepairable:updateBlock:]_block_invoke_2
ProductBuildVersion: 8E2002
ASSERTION FAILURE in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-12175/IDEFoundation/Provisioning/Mechanic/UserActions/IDEProvisioningUserAction.m:125
Details:  method -[IDEProvisioningUserAction userActionName] is a responsibility of subclasses of IDEProvisioningPermissionsFailureUserAction
Object:   <IDEProvisioningPermissionsFailureUserAction: 0x7fed55a409d0>
Method:   -userActionName
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fed4f516d60>{number = 1, name = main}
Hints:   

Backtrace:
  0   -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
  1   _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2   _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3   -[IDEProvisioningUserAction userActionName] (in IDEFoundation)
  4   -[IDEProvisioningRepairStateInfo setWaitingForUserAction:] (in IDEFoundation)
  5   ___DVTAsyncPerformBlockOnMainRunLoop_block_invoke (in DVTFoundation)
  6   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ (in CoreFoundation)
  7   __CFRunLoopDoBlocks (in CoreFoundation)
  8   __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation)
  9   CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation)
 10   RunCurrentEventLoopInMode (in HIToolbox)
 11   ReceiveNextEventCommon (in HIToolbox)
 12   _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter (in HIToolbox)
 13   _DPSNextEvent (in AppKit)
 14   -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in AppKit)
 15   -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in DVTKit)
 16   -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
 17   NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
 18   start (in libdyld.dylib)

abort() called
```

Comment: It is not a permission issue for my developer account because I tried both my personal one and another one, which both results in the same error

Comment: Report the crash to Apple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode was crashing due to insufficient permission in the apple certificate to be able to add the device's UDID to the certificate itself (Which it did not simply say). This error will not happen **if you have administrator permission** with the apple certificate or the **UDID of the apple device has already been added** to the apple certificate. I still have no clue to why my personal developer "Team" still resulted in Xcode crashing as it has no relation to the apple certificate.

Two solutions to this problem:

1. Simply give yourself (Developer Account) administrator permission to the apple certificate (which it will automatically add you UDID to the certificate)
2. Ask the administrator of the apple certificate to simply add the UDID of the apple device to the certificate

**Getting the UDID or Identifier of the device:**
Within Xcode menu bar, Click Window > Devices, and then select your apple device and you should see the "Identifier: XXXXXXXXXXXXX" or UDID