# Xcode 8 crashes when iPhone connected and iPhone is selected as device

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am having a problem where I am trying to run an app on my new iPhone SE in Xcode and when I select the device, Xcode immediately crashes every time.

I tried doing the steps detailed in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2O_8HAsz_gU (creating a certificate, I actually have 3 from trying 3 times, creating an app ID for my project, setting the Device Identifier with the UDID taken from iTunes, and setting up the provisioning profile).

I looked up other answers and people have said to delete the DerivedData folder, but that has not worked. Running in simulator works, just when I switch from simulator to iPhone, Xcode crashes, I don't even have time to press the run button. Anyone have any ideas?

Crash Log:

```
Process:               Xcode [910]  
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode  
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode  
Version:               8.3.2 (12175)  
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-12175000000000000~4  
App Item ID:           497799835  
App External ID:       821771079  
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)  
Parent Process:        ??? [1]  
Responsible:           Xcode [910]  
User ID:               501  
Date/Time:             2017-08-24 16:17:50.359 -0500  
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.12.1 (16B2659)  
Report Version:        12  
Anonymous UUID:        2890CE8E-BFF7-9F5D-B845-5DE445083D6A  
Time Awake Since Boot: 220 seconds  
System Integrity Protection: enabled  
Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread  
Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)  
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000  
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY  
Application Specific Information:  
MainQueue: -[IDEProvisioningManager  
_performStateUpdateOnMainThreadForRepairable:updateBlock:]_block_invoke_2  
ProductBuildVersion: 8E2002  
ASSERTION FAILURE in  
/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-12175/IDEFoundation/Provisioning/Mechanic/UserActions/IDEProvisioningUserAction.m:125
Details:  method -[IDEProvisioningUserAction userActionName] is a 
responsibility of subclasses of IDEProvisioningPermissionsFailureUserAction  

Object:   <IDEProvisioningPermissionsFailureUserAction: 0x7f9139cd9b00>  
Method:   -userActionName  
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7f9131c17710>{number = 1, name = main}
```

Comment: What does the crash log say?

Comment: Just added the crash log

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like permission issue.

> Because the device UDID needs to be added to the developer account you
>   are using.
>
> Once you will add UDID to the account, Xcode should be able to create
>   the provisioning profiles and will not crash.

Check the related thread here: [Xcode 8 crashes when device is selected](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/76849)

Also check the answer here: [XCode 8.3.2 Crashes when switching devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43826579/xcode-8-3-2-crashes-when-switching-devices)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I actually did connect the UDID, but I finally figured out a fix anyways... basically what I think was happening was I had the Automatically Manage Signing box checked, and once I unchecked it and selected the provisioning profiles for the individual project it was able to build. I'm not sure why I didn't have this problem before; I used to be able to just let Xcode automatically manage signing and it would build ok.